# Organization Restrictions on Creating D365 Managed Solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have been told that "to use managed solutions for deployment through Dynamics 365 requires the developing organization to be a certified ISV for Dynamics with Microsoft.  And furthermore, that a Managed Solution also goes through some sort of vetting process within Microsoft."

This sounds like some sort of misunderstanding to me.

From my understanding of the use cases for unmanaged and managed solutions, there is no such restriction on my creation of managed solutions.  All the documentation I have seen mentions the benefits of using managed solutions but does not go into any sort of detail about having to be a certified ISV or that the solution has to be vetted.

I am new to using D365 and am having a hard time determining if what I have been told has any truth to it.  My question is if anyone can clarify if there really is any sort of certification required by my company to use the concept of managed solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small confusion.

Customizing & deploying as a Managed solution (part of internal DevOps) within your organization is not needed to go through vetting process.

Partners/ISVs developing & distributing the Managed solutions through [Dynamics Marketplace aka Appsource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=dynamics-365) has vetting process, Microsoft will review the solutions before publishing in AppSource. This is to make sure the compliance with respect to standard, policies, security aspects.

Comment: This is probably dumb to clarify, but I want to make sure I clearly understand.  When you mention a managed solution as part of our internal DevOps within our organization, the vetting process is not necessary?  I assume that it doesn't matter if our environments are on-prem or in the microsoft cloud, as long as we aren't trying to publish the solutions to the Marketplace, we are good to use managed solutions?

Comment: @feblock352 yes